# Creating a Bundle and adding items to it with Core Service

Tags: core-service, bundles

I am experimenting with creating bundles and adding items to them using the Core Service, and am struggling to find examples of this.

I seem to recall someone telling me that bundles are actually virtual folders, so this is where I got to

```
    VirtualFolderData bundle = (VirtualFolderData)client.GetDefaultData(Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.ItemType.VirtualFolder, bundleFolderURI, new ReadOptions());
    bundle.Title = itemID;
    bundle.Description = "test";
    client.Create(bundle, new ReadOptions());
```

But this fails with a message "No content found". Can anyone point me in the right direction with an example of creating bundles, and adding items to the bundle?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Chris,
I think.. To make it a Bundle you need to change `TypeSchema` to be a Bundle Schema and set another `Configuration` XML:

```
var bundle = (VirtualFolderData) client.GetDefaultData(ItemType.VirtualFolder, "tcm:2-3-2", new ReadOptions());
bundle.Configuration = "<Bundle xmlns=\"http://www.sdltridion.com/ContentManager/Bundle\"><Items /></Bundle>";
bundle.TypeSchema = new LinkToSchemaData{IdRef = "tcm:0-2-8"};
client.Create(bundle, new ReadOptions());
```

And to add items to the Bundle:

```
public static VirtualFolderData AddItemsToBundleConfiguration(this VirtualFolderData bundle, IList<string> itemIdsToAdd)
{
  XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(bundle.Configuration);
  XNamespace xmlns = "http://www.sdltridion.com/ContentManager/Bundle";
  XNamespace xlink = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink";

  foreach (var itemId in itemIdsToAdd)
  {
    XElement newItemNode = new XElement(xmlns + "Item",
        new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xlink", xlink),
        new XAttribute(xlink + "href", itemId)
    );
    doc.Descendants(xmlns + "Items").First().Add(newItemNode);
  }

  bundle.Configuration = doc.ToString();
  return bundle;
}
```

Read the complete story at [Andrey Marchuk's blog](http://amarchuk.blogspot.nl/2013/04/create-update-bundle-through-coreservice.html).

**NOTE:** that the TypeSchema is not the Bundle Schema - [Andrey explains that part here](http://amarchuk.blogspot.nl/2013/04/my-post-httpamarchuk.html)

Comment: Man, if you are copying sample then at least put a link to the original! http://amarchuk.blogspot.nl/2013/04/create-update-bundle-through-coreservice.html?q=bundles

Comment: Yes this is from 
http://amarchuk.blogspot.in/2013/04/create-update-bundle-through-coreservice.html

Comment: That is exactly what I needed, thanks for pointing me in the right direction