# Setting Bundle Namespace in Event System

Tags: event-system, bundles

I am trying to create a new Bundle in the Event System.  However, I get the following error message:
Unable to save item.  Unexpected namespace URI: uuid:b2054ef9-904f-49d8-8b7f-40523bb88536. Expecting: http://www.sdltridion.com/ContentManager/Bundle

I do not see a namespace property on the bundle object.  I am thinking to use UpdateXML and change the namespace - but it feels wrong and feels like Tridion should be setting the correct namespace for me.

Is there another way to set this namespace?

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using Tridion.ContentManager;
using Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement;
using Tridion.ContentManager.Extensibility;
using Tridion.ContentManager.Extensibility.Events;

namespace EventSystemBundles
{
    [TcmExtension("AutoCreateBundle")]
    public class AutoCreateBundle : TcmExtension
    {
        public AutoCreateBundle()
        {
            Subscribe();
        }

        public void Subscribe()
        {
           // InitLog();

            // OnComponentSavePre
            EventSystem.Subscribe<Component, SaveEventArgs>(OnComponentSavePre, EventPhases.Initiated);
        }

        private static void OnComponentSavePre(Component comp, SaveEventArgs args, EventPhases phase)
        {
            string bundleFolderUri = "tcm:11-44-2";  // read from config or folder meta later...
            string bundleTypeSchemaUri = "tcm:11-461-8";
            Session session = comp.Session;

            try
            {
                TcmUri uri = new TcmUri(bundleFolderUri);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle(session, uri);
                bundle.Title = "Bundle for " + comp.Title;
                Schema bundleSchema = (Schema)session.GetObject(bundleTypeSchemaUri);
                bundle.TypeSchema = bundleSchema;
                bundle.Save();

                //uuid:b2054ef9-904f-49d8-8b7f-40523bb88536. Expecting: http://www.sdltridion.com/ContentManager/Bundle
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }

            comp.Title = "a " + comp.Title;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you are setting `Bundle schema` as `BundleType schema`. 
Read [this](http://amarchuk.blogspot.nl/2013/04/my-post-httpamarchuk.html) to understand it better.

Basically you need to determine your "true" bundle type schema and set bundle schema you are setting as `MetadataSchema`

Comment: Yes, when I read 'MetadataSchema' I was not thinking this is the 'BundleType' schema as the Tridion GUI tells me.  Too bad they didn't call it 'BundleTypeSchema' and remove the need for confusion...

Comment: I removed the bundle.TypeSchema and replaced it with bundle.MetadataSchema and it works great.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem when [creating bundles with the core service](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/1648/creating-a-bundle-and-adding-items-to-it-with-core-service). Here is my working code:

```
    String typeSchemaId = client.GetList("tcm:0-0-7", new OrganizationalItemItemsFilterData()).Single(s => s.Title == "Bundle").Id;
    String imageworkflowschema = "tcm:4-9170-8";

    VirtualFolderData bundle = (VirtualFolderData)client.GetDefaultData(Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.ItemType.VirtualFolder, bundleFolderURI, new ReadOptions());
    bundle.Title = "Test:" + DateTime.Now.ToFileTimeUtc();
    bundle.Configuration = bundleConfigXML.ToString();
    bundle.TypeSchema = new LinkToSchemaData { IdRef = typeSchemaId };
    bundle.MetadataSchema = new LinkToSchemaData { IdRef = imageworkflowschema };
    bundle = (VirtualFolderData)client.Create(bundle, new ReadOptions());
```

The tricky part was finding `typeSchemaId`. I also confused the `BundleType` and the `Bundle` Schemas.