# How to find Type of event subscribed for an action using core servce

Tags: core-service, 2013-sp1

Is there any way/method/properties to find out what type of event will trigger for a CMS action. e.g. I am trying to create a new page using core service. Currently If I create a page in CMS manually then it creates a default component and attached it to page and ask me to add the page in a Bundle. Now how to find all these events attached to page creation using Core service and execute them ?

Comment: It will be useful if you can tag the version of CMS.

Comment: It's 2013 SP1..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether you create page using core service or do it manually, same set of events are triggered.

You don't need to explicitly invoke event system.

Comment: Can you help me then how to pass Bundle Information to which the page should be get added after creation ?

Comment: You can refer to link: http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/1648/creating-a-bundle-and-adding-items-to-it-with-core-service for adding items to bundle.

Answer (score 0):

Core Service is a WCF web service. The event system talks to TOM.Net which is a .Net class library.

Clients that use the Core Service API can be run anywhere (as long as they can reach at least one endpoint exposed by Core Service).
Clients that use the TOM.Net API must run on a server that has Tridion CM installed.

As a *strong* recommendation you should use the TOM.Net API only for C# templating (assembly or C# fragment TBBs) and Event System. As another *strong* recommendation you should not use the Core Service in either of those.

As such the use of these APIs can be seen as mutually exclusive; you use *either* Core Service *or* TOM.Net.

What you are suggesting is to call event system code (which uses TOM.Net) manually from a core service client application (which uses Core Service) which violates above principle.

Comment: Thanks for clerifying the TOM.NET and Core service basic.